# ORA-20010: DBMS_STATS INTERNAL ERROR in fill_cstats : both dmin/dmax and nmin/nmax are null for table SOA , column KEY , ssize 29892

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
ORA-20010: DBMS_STATS INTERNAL ERROR in fill_cstats : both dmin/dmax and nmin/nmax are null for table SOA, column KEY , ssize 29892
ORA-06512: at "MOSTI", line 165
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

The above error occurred in production, can someone please explain why it has occurred and solution?

Comment: This is an internal error in Oracle's built-in DBSM_STATS gathering routine. As such you need to raise an SR with Oracle Support. If you don't have a Support contract then you may be out of luck. Are you gathering histograms? Is the table partitioned?

Comment: Table is partitioned. Not gathering histogram.

Comment: So you may be running into [a known bug](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2302863_1.html). Alas that only helps if you have a Support contract.

Answer (score 2):

It seems due to an oracle internal bug.

> ORA-20010: DBMS_STATS INTERNAL ERROR In Fill_cstat During Analyze A
>   Table (文档 ID 2247315.1)

Getting following error when gathering the table statistics:

> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'S', tabname => 'TEST',
>   estimate_percent => 100, cascade => TRUE, granularity=> 'ALL', degree
>   => 2, no_invalidate=>FALSE);
>   * ERROR at line 1: ORA-20010: DBMS_STATS INTERNAL ERROR in fill_cstats : both dmin/dmax and nmin/nmax are null for table S.TEST , column
>   FIRST_NAME , ssize 430241 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 34757
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

1. The bug is fixed in 12.2
2. Workaround for the bug is to delete statistics and re-gather statistics
3. If the above workaround does not work, another potential workaround is using parallel degree of 1:

`SYS@EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'SCOTT', tabname => 'TEST', estimate_percent => 100, cascade => TRUE, degree => 1);`

but it matches oracle 12.1